# Сгенерировать html страницу в node.js

Tags: node.js, сервер

Подскажите, как в nodejs сервере сгенерировать страницу, которая будет отображать содержимое директории, в которой находится скрипт сервера. Чтобы было как, например, в Денвере, зайдя на 127.0.0.1 - видим содержимое директории www.

Comment: В денвере этим, скорее всего, занимается фронтенд, а не бекенд.

Если ты в качестве фронтенда используешь nginx, то всё решается просто: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html

Если же нет... я бы поставил. Или google в помощь https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=node+js+directory+listing

Comment: если мы в денвере заходи на локалхост и видим список файлов, то денвер не настроен

Answer (score 1):

Ну в принципе простым выводом в консоль через модуль fs., я такое делал, но, конечно, с интерактивностью вывода чуть сложнее.